# FOSRestBundle No route found

Tags: php, fosrestbundle

I'm having difficulty getting a call to an API working using FOSRestBundle.

```
users:
    type:     rest
    resource: GU\GreetupBundle\Controller\UsersController
```

.

```
class UsersController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{

    public function postUserLocationAction($id, Request $request)
    {

        var_dump($request->attributes); die();
    }
}
```

According to the documentation this should work:

```
curl {{url}}/users/:id/location
```

but I get the following `No route found for "POST /users/1/location"`

Answer (score 0):

Using `bin/console debug:router` should help you.

It returns all the routes registered and you will be able to find the one corresponding to your controller (for debugging).

Once it's done, don't hesitate to add more informations to be helped further ;)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: That's what i wanted to do but i can't comment yet... I'll try to improve my answer but it would be easier with the output of this command.